# Horizontal Menu Slider

Tags: html, css

I am in need of a horizontal menu scroll, but I am struggling to get to work the way I need it to. I have no knowledge of javascript, if someone could let me know how to implement javascript to php, that would be fantastic! I have been stuck on this for 2 days.

This is what I need it to be...

what I need;
[image]

and this is what I have so far;
[image]

as you can see below my css and html:

```css
.main-nav-bar {
 background-color: #333;
}
.scrollmenu {
 width: 500px;
}
div.scrollmenu {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav-bar">
  <div class="scrollmenu">
     <a href="#home">Home</a>
     <a href="#news">News</a>
     <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
     <a href="#about">About</a>
     <a href="#support">Support</a>
     <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
     <a href="#tools">Tools</a>  
     <a href="#base">Base</a>
     <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
     <a href="#more">More</a>
     <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
     <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
     <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
     <a href="#people">People</a>
     <a href="#work">Work</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I would appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: To use javascript in your php, you need to insert a the html <script> tag and enter here some javascript...
I don't really know how to help you with this... Maybe you should also show us your php code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet below, I think this will be good start for you:

```css
.main-nav-bar {
 background-color: #333;
}
.scrollmenu {
 width: 500px;
}
div.scrollmenu {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

div.scrollmenu::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; 
}

div.scrollmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav-bar">
    <div class="scrollmenu">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#support">Support</a>
        <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
        <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
        <a href="#base">Base</a>
        <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
        <a href="#more">More</a>
        <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
        <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
        <a href="#people">People</a>
        <a href="#work">Work</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this blog https://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/horizontal-scrolling-responsive-menu , hope this helps :)